# Accessing complex types in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I've used Glue to generate tables for Athena. I have some nested array/struct values (complex types) that I'm having trouble accessing via query.

I have two tables, the one in question is named "sample_parquet".

```
 ids (array<struct<idType:string,idValue:string>>)
```

The the cell has the value:

```
[{idtype=ttd_id, idvalue=cf275376-8116-4cad-a035-e241e14b1470}, {idtype=md5_email, idvalue=932babe184fb11c92b09b3e13e936124}]
```

And I've tried:

```
 select ids.idtype from sample_parquet limit 1
```

Which yields:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Expression "ids" is not of type ROW
```

And:

```
select s.idtype from sample_parquet.ids s limit 1;
```

Which yields:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:22: Schema sample_parquet does not exist
```

I've also tried:

```
select json_extract(ids, '$.idtype') as idtype from sample_parquet limit 1;
```

Which yields:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 8:8: Unexpected parameters (array(row(idtype varchar,idvalue varchar)), varchar(8)) for function json_extract. Expected: json_extract(varchar(x), JsonPath) , json_extract(json, JsonPath)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried to `UNNEST ids`, since you have an array of structs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the elements of an array like you'd access a dictionary/key-value.

Use UNNEST to flatten the array and then you can use the `.` operator.

For more information on working with JSONs and ARRAYs on [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html).

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me: select idvalue.idvalue, idvalue.idtype from sample_parquet cross join unnest(ids) as t(idvalue)

Answer (score 0):

`ids` is a column of type array, not a relation (e.g. a table, view, or a subquery). Confusingly, when dealing with nested types in Athena/Presto you have to stop thinking in terms of SQL and instead think more as you would in a programming language.

There are dedicated functions that act on [arrays](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html), [maps](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/map), as well as [lambda functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html) (no relationship with the AWS service), that can be used to dig into nested types.

When you say `SELECT ids.idtype …` I assume that what you're after could be written like `ids.map((id) => id.ittype)` in JavaScript. In Athena/Presto this could be expressed as `SELECT transform(ids, id -> id.idtype) …`.

The result of `transform` will be a relation with a column of type `array<string>`. If you want each element of that array as a separate row, you need to use [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/sql/select.html#unnest), but if you instead want the first value you can use the [`element_at`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html#element_at) function. There are also other functions that you may be familiar with such as `filter`, `slice`, and `flatten` that produce new arrays, as well as `reduce`, which produce a scalar value.